# Delete specific rows from a table with billions of rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a huge SQL table with billions of rows. For example, if I have to `DELETE` records for only particular dates. what is the best approach.

```
Delete * from dbo.table where date in ('date1','date2','date3')
```

Please suggest

Comment: Do you know what type of if any index is on the date field.

Comment: Would you mind stating what problem are you having? Is it too slow? Is it blowing up your log? Is it eating all memory? Try out your approach. If you are not satisfied, come back with the problem.

Comment: Use an index on your date column, and I'd use a `where dateColumn between 'date1' and 'dateN'` clause

Comment: @ZoffDino: Agreed. =)

Answer (score 3):

```
WHILE (1 = 1)
BEGIN
   DELETE TOP (10000)
      FROM Table_Name
   WHERE DATE_COLUMN = '20140101'  --<-- ANSI DATE format  YYYYMMDD
       OR
         DATE_COLUMN = '20140102'
       OR
         DATE_COLUMN = '20140103'

     IF (@@ROWCOUNT < 1)
       BEGIN 
         BREAK;
       END   
END
```

Comment: I'm curious; why is this better than the OP's SQL?

Comment: The batching technique will mitigate log space needs and improve concurrency, assuming an index exists on the date column.

Comment: @DeanOC see http://sqlperformance.com/2013/03/io-subsystem/chunk-deletes