# Deleting billion of rows in an oracle db

Tags: sql, oracle

I have to delete a lot of rows from our log db.
Currently, the table holds about 6.3 billion of rows that I want to delete.

First of all, I'm doing it right now (until I have a better solution) in million increments via Python, which takes around ~600 seconds on average per million.

I've tried to copy the data we need (which is around 3% of all data in this table) in another table, but an error occurred because the data amounts too much, it seems, to insert that via select into another table.
(my plan was to get the data we need, insert it into another table, and just delete the old one and rename the new table)

I found this one too:
[Delete specific rows from a table with billions of rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25633786/delete-specific-rows-from-a-table-with-billions-of-rows)

Is that the best approach for me? (my procedure writing skills are nearly non existent, so I'm a little scared to try this, that's why I'm doing it with Python right now)

Thank you for any advice

**Edit:**
My Python Code:

```
import time
from helperfunc import dbExecAny


def delete_lg_log():
    dbExecAny("delete from inspire.lg_log WHERE lg_wp_type  != 'Matching.SAP.Zahlstatus' and rownum <= 1000000")

i = 0
while i <= 6200:
    i += 1
    print(f"Process loop {i}")
    start = time.time()
    delete_lg_log()
    end = time.time()
    print(start - end)
```

delete function:

```
def dbExecAny(stmt, db_name=""):
    try:
        if db_name.lower() == "cobra":
            a_cur = cobra_conn.cursor()
        else:
            a_cur = conn.cursor()
        if "drop" in stmt.lower() in stmt.lower() or "truncate" in stmt.lower() or "where" not in stmt.lower():
            print("Invalid statement: " + stmt)
            return []
        a_cur.execute(stmt)
        return a_cur.execute(stmt)
    except Exception as e:
        print("Coult not execute statement " + stmt + ", error: " + str(e))
        return []
    finally:
        conn.commit()
```

Comment: And I'm guessing no one ever bothered to define partitions for that table?

Comment: Sounds like you should copy the data to be retained into another table in batches, and then truncate the  source table.

Comment: @tinazmu - in batches? how many times would you like to scan 6.3 billion rows?

Comment: Are you deleting the 1 million rows in a transaction?

Comment: Link is for SQL Server and not Oracle, two different RDBMSs.

Comment: 3% is about 300 million rows, you can scan 10 times. One could also export that 3% to text or something, and then import. What was the error when inserting into another table?

Comment: @tinazmu I don't have the error on hand and it tock about an hour until the error occured, so I can't reproduce it without losing alot of time.

Comment: @DavidדודוMarkovitz I don't know, I'm not the db admin and my db knowledge is to low to give you an correct answer.

Comment: @RyanVincent I delete a million rows, commit, and delete the next million

Comment: Just to confirm about using transactions... `start transaction` ... `delete rows` ... `commit`.  I am surprised it is so slow.  Have you done a trace on it to find out where the time is being spent?

Comment: I can post you my code, but I think that's how it is.

Comment: @user3793935, you are doing an admin tasks and this information is crucial

Comment: @DavidדודוMarkovitz what do you mean by scan btw? Selects? If yes .. as little as possible, since a count takes about an hour on the table.
And yes, in batches, I delete 1million rows at the time

Comment: If you have partitions, you can split a big CTAS task to smaller serialized/parallized tasks, scanning the entire data only once. If you don't have partitions you need to scan the data over and over again. P.S. if you have the right partitions you might not even need to delete anything, just drop/truncate the relevant partitions

Comment: @DavidדודוMarkovitz I can't do that, I think ;( I'm not in the db team, so jeah, I don't really know if I have the permissions to do that and if I could do that, my knowledge to perfom stuff like that would be to low. I would be to scared to break something ;(

Comment: That's an organizational problem, way out of SO scope.

Comment: @DavidדודוMarkovitz yeah, it's more of an communication problem. We never noticed that some processes fill the logs as much as they do -.-
But let me rephrase the quesion:
If I delete stuff from such a large table with an where clause, is it faster to delete in like 10 million batches instead of 1 million batches? (I don't want to experiment since every test takes such a long time ... I've tryed it of course with like 100 and the time was muuuuch longer than expected aka 60 seconds for 100 rows, but 600 seconds for 1 million)

Comment: With rate of 1 million records per 600 seconds, this task is expected to complete within 40 days. Are you sure you don't want to escalate?

Comment: @DavidדודוMarkovitz jeah, I know the time ;( I still have the hopes that it will get faster and faster the more stuff gets deleted.
The problem is, that It's more or less to be expected, that it's done at monday. 
But if we would use your technique, do you think it would be doable in a few hours?

Comment: It's not something you need to do, the partitions on this table either exist, or not and even if partitions were defined, there are not necessarily well defined. This should be validated by a DBA.

Comment: Retaining 3% of rows in a table is **absolutely not** the task for `delete` regardless of the size of batch: will it be 1, 10 or 100 millions per batch, it will take proportionally long time to complete and will not solve the problem. The problem is an absence of partitioning and nothing else. It would be better to copy that 3% of data to a different table, truncate an original table, repartition it and move 3% back. Maybe you should plan a downtime to stop applications from writing new logs if `select` is also slow

Answer (score 2):

The quickest way to save your 3% of data that should remain is to do a ctas (Create Table As Select) from your source table with no logging option. After that truncate your source table, drop it and rename the newly created table.
Don’t forget about things like dependencies like indexes, triggers, constraints and privileges.

This no logging only works if the database is not in force logging mode because it needs to keep a standby database in sync.

Comment: I've allready tryed that approach. But I can't. I get an error, because the amount I wont to copy to another table equals maybe 300 GB?
I googled that error and I was told that you can only do that for max 32 GB

Comment: What error did you get exactly? Did you have enough datafiles for the tablespace available? That 3% equals about 300GB? Then have at least that amount of space available.

Comment: unable to extend temp segment by %s in tablespace %s
That was the error.
And I don't know the real amount of data. 
That's an estimate by what i was told about when we wanted to migrate our applikation into the cloud. ( 4tb --> at least 3 tb is the one table + some other stuff that we don't need anymore)

Comment: I am surprised you needed any temp segment for a straight `insert`. Did the query include a `distinct` or `order by` or hash join etc? Or you could incrementally insert into the other table, say 10M rows at a time, as it's a lot less resource-intensive than deletion.

Comment: That 32GB is typically the size of a datafile. Make enough of them available in that tablespace.